# tmux on a Mac: how can I move the divider lines?

Tags: macos, tmux

On my Linux system I use prefix (redefined as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> for me) that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd> to move the divider line but this isn't working on my new Mac. Any idea how I can move the divider lines?

Comment: When I disable Ctrl-Left/Ctrl-Right as Mission Control shortcuts, they aren't recognized by iTerm at all. In Terminal, I have a keyboard shortcut that uses them to send "\033[5d" and "\033[5C", respectively; I don't recall if that is a default or if I added it myself. In any case, what appears on the command line of your Linux box if you type Ctrl-V Ctrl-Left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your terminal, ctrl-arrow may not be sending a recognized character sequence to `tmux`. Since it works on Linux, determine what sequence your terminal generates for ctrl-arrow, then configure your Mac terminal do send the same.

Comment: Alt-arrow is also moving the divider line.

Comment: prefix (ctrl+a in my case too) then option + arrows works on my mac

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
tmux bind-key k resize-pane -U
```

to remap <kbd>k</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>.